# javascript/jquery getImageData color pick of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, colors, getimagedata

I have this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/R6rGp/

I try to pick up the color of an image/canvas but I always get RGB 000.

But obviously, the image has no real black pixels. What's wrong with that?

```
document.getElementById("canvas").onload=function(){
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height);

red=imgData.data[0];
green=imgData.data[1];
blue=imgData.data[2];
alpha=imgData.data[3];

console.log(red + " " + green + " " + blue + " " + alpha); //always 0 0 0


ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);


};
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) doesn't allow cross-origin data:

`Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

And it seems that there's another problem in your script too:

`Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18`.